# radio button for django forms.py and models.py

Tags: python, django

Hi i try to create a radio option in my form, i created all the relevant code for that. But the field is not comming in radio option its in dropdown or checkbox. I dont know what mistake i am doing. I gave my code here. Please check it and give some solution for this.

**forms.py**

```
like = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=BOOL_CHOICES, widget=RadioSelect, coerce=bool)
```

**models.py**

```
 BOOL_CHOICES = ((True, 'male'), (False, 'female'))
 like= models.BooleanField(choices=BOOL_CHOICES)
```

**views.py**

```
 like = product_form.cleaned_data['like']
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code might work... havn't tested

```
 BOOL_CHOICES = ((True, 'male'), (False, 'female'))
 like = forms.ChoiceField(choices=BOOL_CHOICES , widget=forms.RadioSelect())
```

Below line is from my application and is working fine..

```
CHOICES = (('1','Teacher'),('2','Student'))
accountAs =  forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=CHOICES, error_messages={'required':"Please select account type"})
```

Comment: ya i did this..but dropdown buton is comming

Answer (score 0):

You need ChoiceField instead of TypedChoiceField

```
# forms.py
like = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=BOOL_CHOICES)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#widgets-inheriting-from-the-select-widget

Comment: i tried your code..its not working for radio option..dropdown is displaying

Comment: yet i dint get radio option